# Hi i am getting user is AnonymousUser even i am passing valid token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

hi i am using djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.4.0 and creating token using it [image]
but django give me AnonymousUser when i am trying to pass this token in side Authorization  Bearer 
my restframework setting is :

```
    
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 
    )

}

from datetime import timedelta

...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=50),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=60),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

view code is given below where i am trying to use it

```
class PostProductsReviewsView(CreateAPIView):
    # permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ReviewsSerializer
    
    def get(self,request):
        print(request.user)
        user_id=request.user.id
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        except:
            return Response({"error":"user is not authenticated"},status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        data=request.data
        stars=data.get('stars')
        title=data.get('title')
        review_content=data.get('review_content')
        review_content=data.get('product')
        quesry_data={
            'stars':stars,
            'title':title,
            'review_content':review_content,
            'user':user,
            'is_active':True
        }
        # data['user']=user
        serializer=ReviewsSerializer(data=quesry_data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

please help me when i copy and test on jwt.io this token contain all details but show invalid signature please help me

Comment: i figure out some thing is wrong with signing key  .please help me how to make it working

Comment: Can you share how you used the token in the header?

Comment: hi BrianD this is not same ```  Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MywiZXhwIjoxNjM3OTk1MDczLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InBzYXVuZGFyeTEiLCJpbWFnZSI6bnVsbH0.8ahZ-_0txDL1fri_UpJnNRe6m7D6rL5ER78P8NwV1tg  ```  token but i am pasing it like this way, i just skip to find why it is happen but i found that by mistake i just import django filter and pagination inside top of my settings.py may be this is the reason